# Для чего нужны 2 цикла: for и foreach?

Tags: java, массивы, foreach, for

Вопросы:

1. Для чего нужен `foreach`, если можно перебирать массив к примеру через цикл `for`?
2. Можно ли сделать задачу с массивами например на `foreach` и на цикле `for` обычном, чтобы получить по итогу один и тот же результат?
3. Зачем нам `foreach` если есть `for`?

Нашел вот такой пример, но почему-то не получается реализовать его на foreach:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int numer[] = {4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};
        int denom[] = {2, 2, 4, 4, 2, 8};

        for (int i = 0; i < numer.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(numer[i] + " / " + denom[i] + " равно " + numer[i] / denom[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавлю к ответам: foreach всегда можно заменить for'ом, а for foreach'ем - только в конкретных ситуациях.

Comment: @Anton238 не всегда. Вспомните про итератор

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ответы на вопросы:

1. `foreach` укорачивает код для перебора коллекций (списки, массивы и т.п.), когда нам нужно только получить элементы из них, без работы с индексами.

   Примеры для `foreach`:

   ```
   int numer[] = {4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};
   for (int i : numer) {
       System.out.println(i);
   }

   List<String> items = Arrays.asList("1", "abc");
   for (String word : items) {
       System.out.println(word);
   }

   Map<String, String> nameByValue = new HashMap<>();
   nameByValue.put("name", "Vasya");
   nameByValue.put("email", "pupkin@email.mail");

   for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : nameByValue.entrySet()) {
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
   }
   ```

   Через стандартный цикл:

   ```
   int numer[] = {4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};
   for (int i = 0; i < numer.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(numer[i]);
   }

   List<String> items = Arrays.asList("1", "abc");
   for (int i = 0; i < items.size(); i++) {
       String word = items.get(i);
       System.out.println(word);
   }

   Map<String, String> nameByValue = new HashMap<>();
   nameByValue.put("name", "Vasya");
   nameByValue.put("email", "pupkin@email.mail");

   // Через for:
   // for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = nameByValue.entrySet().iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
   // 
   // Через while более предпочтительнее чем через for
   Iterator<Map.Entry<String, String>> it = nameByValue.entrySet().iterator();
   while (it.hasNext()) {
       Map.Entry<String, String> entry = it.next();
       System.out.println(entry.getKey() + " = " + entry.getValue());
   }
   ```
2. Можно. Но придется для `foreach` сгенерировать коллекцию с индексами.
3. Чтобы код перебора коллекции был короче. Пример:

   ```
   int numer[] = {4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};

   for (int i = 0; i < numer.length; i++) {
       System.out.println(numer[i] + " * 2 -> " + numer[i] * 2);
   }

   System.out.println();

   for (int i : numer) {
       System.out.println(i + " * 2 -> " + i * 2);
   }
   ```

Код:

```
static List<Integer> getRange(int length) {
    List<Integer> items = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        items.add(i);
    }

    return items;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    int numer[] = {4, 8, 16, 32, 64, 128};
    int denom[] = {2, 2, 4,   4,  2, 8};

    for (int i = 0; i < numer.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(numer[i] + " / " + denom[i] + " равно " + numer[i] / denom[i]);
    }

    System.out.println();

    for (int i : getRange(numer.length)) {
        System.out.println(numer[i] + " / " + denom[i] + " равно " + numer[i] / denom[i]);
    }
}
```

Консоль:

```
4 / 2 равно 2
8 / 2 равно 4
16 / 4 равно 4
32 / 4 равно 8
64 / 2 равно 32
128 / 8 равно 16

4 / 2 равно 2
8 / 2 равно 4
16 / 4 равно 4
32 / 4 равно 8
64 / 2 равно 32
128 / 8 равно 16
```

Comment: "foreach укорачивает код" укорачивает ли? Если только визуально, компилируется же, наверняка, то же самое?

Comment: @Isaev, под кодом обычно подразумевается текстовый код, а не байт-код или машинный код

Answer (score 5):

`foreach` работает c итераторами.

```
List<String> someIterable = List.of("1", "2");
for (Iterator<String> i = someIterable.iterator(); i.hasNext();) {
    String item = i.next();
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Этот цикл эквивалентен записи:

```
for(String str : someIterable){
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

У обычного массива итератор отсутствует.

Запись вида:

```
for (int numeri : numer) {
    System.out.println(numeri);
}
```

Является синтаксическим сахаром, так как преобразуется в следующий вид

```
int len = numer.length;
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    int numeri = numer[i];
    System.out.println(numeri);
}
```

Но тем не менее, `foreach` спроектирован для работы с текущим элементом одной структуры, а вам необходимо взять i-ый элемент у двух массивов `numer` и `denom`

Comment: Массивы тоже итерируются через foreach: `for (int i : numer) {System.out.println(i);}`

Answer (score 4):

Дополню ответ @gil9red информацией по другим сценариям использования for-each.

> 1. Для чего нужен foreach, если можно перебирать массив к примеру через цикл for?

for-each, а точнее усовершенствованный цикл for (enhanced for loop), задумывался в первую очередь для облегчения работы с коллекциями через итератор. Поддержка массивов добавлена для единообразия кода.

Не все коллекции, которые поддерживают перебор через итератор, поддерживают обращение по индексу. Например, множество можно перебрать через for-each:

```
Set<String> letters = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b"));
for(String letter : letters) {
     //...
}
```

При этом цикл пройдет по всем элементам множества, но порядок элементов не гарантируется. Обращение к элементу множества по индексу не имеет смысла:

```
for(int i=0; i<letters.size(); i++) { 
     letters.get(i); //такого метода нет
}
```

Т.о. как минимум для коллекций for-each нельзя заменить циклом for по индексу. Для коллекций for-each соответствует циклу for с итератором:

```
Collection c = ... ;
for (Iterator i = c.iterator(); i.hasNext(); ) {  
    String s = (String) i.next();
}
```

Перебор коллекции это операция, которая выполняется очень часто, поэтому в язык и ввели синтаксический сахар, который позволяет сократить код и, соответственно, избежать трудноуловимых ошибок при постоянном использовании одного и того же шаблонного кода. Такое обоснование дается в поправке к спецификации Java ([JSR-201](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=201)) в которой был введен усовершенствованный цикл for:

> Enhanced for loops allow convenient iteration over collections, without the need for an explicitly defined iterator. This reduces the need for boilerplate iteration code and the corresponding opportunities for errors.
>
> *Усовершенствованный цикл for предостваляет удобный способ перебора коллекций, без необходимости явного указания итератора. Это сокращает необходимость создания шаблонного кода для перебора и снижает вероятность возникновения связанных с ним ошибок.*

Собственно, по такой же причине в Java имеется три разных оператора цикла (for, while, do-while) хотя, технически, можно было бы обойтись любым из них.

> 2. Можно ли сделать задачу с массивами например на foreach и на цикле for обычном, чтобы получить по итогу один и тот же результат?

Можно вывернуться конечно, используя список индексов, как в ответе @gil9red, либо используя счетчик:

```
int counter = 0;
for (int n : numer) {
    System.out.println(n + " / " + denom[counter] + " равно " + n / denom[counter]);
    counter++;
}
```

либо создав целую иерархию классов:

```
DivisionBatch divisions = new DivisionBatch(numer, denom);
for(Division division : divisions) {
     System.out.println(division.getNumerator() + "/" + division.getDenominator() + " равно " + divison.getResult());
}
```

Но, по-моему, в данном примере преимущества for-each (сокращение кода для перебора) не проявляются и целесообразнее использовать for.