# Оператор forech против for при работе со списками

Tags: java, foreach, списки, for

простите если повтор, я совсем новенький, ещё не разобрался.
Вопрос: при работе со списками часто использую циклы для перебора элементов. 
Цикл for позволяет добавлять,изменять,удалять элементы списка. 
Цикл foreach не позволяет добавлять,изменять или удалять элементы без итератора.
Какой тогда смысл использовать foreach если в нём, чтоб что-то сделать со списком нужно создавать итератор,соответственно писать больше кода и как я понимаю будет дольше выполнятся программа ну и больше съедать памяти.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/943840/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB-foreach-%D0%B2-java

Comment: Например чтобы только прочитать данные

Comment: Еще похожий вопрос: [Для чего нужны 2 цикла: for и foreach?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/905862/%D0%94%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-2-%D1%86%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0-for-%D0%B8-foreach)

Comment: Цикл foreach - это синтаксический сахар, т.е. "надстройка", которая уменьшает объем кода который надо писать и делает код красивее. В основном нет разницы что использовать, for или foreach